# Can gnome terminal be set up, to copy selection without prompt?

Tags: linux, terminal, gnome, copy-paste, clipboard

I often times want to copy a set of commands from terminal, that do not have an output; say a block like this:

```
prompt$ less file1.txt
prompt$ less file2.txt
prompt$ dhex file2.txt
prompt$ less file3.txt
```

Now, if I select this block of text with the mouse, and copy it with Ctrl-Shift-C; then when I paste in a text file, the prompt is there (as expected) - and then I have to waste time deleting the prompt `:)`

So I was wandering - is there a setting for gnome-terminal, such that when I do the same kind of copying, I end up with only the commands - without the prompt? This is what I want when I finally paste:

```
less file1.txt
less file2.txt
dhex file2.txt
less file3.txt
```

I'm interested in a solution that will allow me to get this in clipboard, with just mouse selection and Ctrl-Shift-C; I am aware I could do `history X`, but then I'd have to `grep` it - and think of a suitable grep expression (and the same problem is if I record a typescript of terminal session with `script`).

Any facilities that exist for that? If not for `gnome-terminal`, any other terminal that can be used under Gnome that offers such facility?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I was quite bugged by this problem, so finally I coded a solution which comes very close: a filtering plugin for the Glipper clipboard manager, which allows for regex processing in filter functions, which can be applied to the clipboard contents upon a Copy action; released here:

- [Bug #1166534 “Enhancement: a regex filtering Glipper plugin” : Bugs : Glipper](https://bugs.launchpad.net/glipper/+bug/1166534)

... and here is a screenshot:

[image: glipper-filter.png]

However, since I want to use this only occasionally, toggling filtering may not be the best idea (since you have to toggle ON, copy/paste, and then toggle OFF) - so the plugin bypasses normal operation when a filter submenu entry is clicked, if <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>c</kbd> are held; so my "minimal" action to perform a one-off prompt filtering is like this:

- Select a region of text (including prompts) in terminal
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> (default shortcut) to bring up Glipper menu window
- Keeping any (or all) of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>c</kbd> held pressed,

  - hover over Filtering menu item
  - hover over and click desired filter (sub)menu item (e.g. `TermCmdLog`)
- Glipper menu dissapears - held keys can now be released
- Move pointer and click to focus text editor
- Paste - the pasted contents are modified by the clicked filter (e.g. for `TermCmdLog` the input has prompts removed, and non-prompt lines commented)

In the end, I would still have preferred that the terminal itself has a keyboard chord for filtered output (say, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, then release <kbd>a</kbd>, then while holding the others press <kbd>c</kbd>) - but then that would be OK for a single filter; and if you want to choose one from several filters at runtime, again there is the problem of having of yet another action to do a choice; and if it is solved via GUI window of menu entries - then this pluggin is just as good, I guess. Even better, it works for any GUI source of (copyable) text under Gnome desktop - not just for terminal.

Unfortunately, it's developed for Gnome/Gtk 2 / Python 2.7, so it's already deprecated; still, hope it can hope others (until I hear of a better solution - hopefully in this thread `:)`),
Cheers!

Comment: wish the screenshot is not shrinked...

Answer (score 2):

In Gnome Terminal, you can select a block of text using Mouse + CTRL key.
This way you can copy all of the console output without the prompt. e.g:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using bash as your shell, you might just do something like:

`history -a ; tail -5 $HISTFILE`

replacing 5 with however many commands you want to go back.  That should get you a clean listing that will copy/paste easily.  Not *exactly* the kind of approach you seem to be fishing for, but it might suit.

Comment: Many thanks for that, @JasonSherman - unfortunately, that only includes the terminal commands, not the output. I did come close in  [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/580073/39752), which I accepted (until I hear of anything better, at least). Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you use, tmux terminal multiplexer, you can do this easily and much more!

Noam Manos already pointed out in the other answer Gnome Terminal does allow block copy with Ctrl + Mouse click and drag. I just wanted to point out another alternative which is more powerful. The tmux supports putting your terminal in "copy mode" and allows you to do block copy and much more -- It even supports multiple paste buffers that you can copy and use later.

I use following lines in my .tmux.conf file to use vi keybindings for block copy:

```
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi v send-keys -X begin-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi y send-keys -X copy-selection
bind-key -T copy-mode-vi r send-keys -X rectangle-toggle
```

It does take some effort to learn to setup and use tmux, but it is worth it and I am happy with it.